# Proof for minimum number of String Rotation Problem

Tags: string, algorithm, string-algorithm

Let's say we are rotating a string one at a time ("abcd" -> "bcda"). After some t rotations we get the same string. Let t be the minimum such number of rotations.

For ex:

1. For S = "aaaa", t = 1
2. For S = "abcabc", t = 3
3. For S = "abcdef", t = 6

Now my question is, can there be any string for which this condition holds : t > len(S)/2 and t < len(S)? If not can you please explain why?

Comment: Do you want a full proof? Or just an _educated guess_? Have you attempted anything yet to prove it yourself?

Comment: @Zabuzard As I understood, you are trying to prove using a constructive approach. You start with a prefix-free string, let's say "ab". And then to get a string for which t < len(S), you basically have to construct "abab" for which t < len(S) holds, and it would be len(S)/2.

What if we start with string that is not prefix free. For ex S = "ababa" t = 5. 
Can you please elaborate and explain your intuition? 

Will t always be divisor of len(S)?
Also, what are minimum number of characters I need to add to get t < len(S)?

Comment: @Zabuzard Just an educated guess, an intuition perhaps.

Comment: Observe that no matter what `t` is, if u repeat rotation by `t` it always ends up with the same string again. To increase the size of `t` you also have to decrease the amount of repeated rotations by `t` until you receive the *original string* (all characters back at original position). That is `3` for `hellohellohello` and `2` for `hellohello`. The next possible value is `1`, but that already gives you `hello` with `t = len(S)`. Hence, there is no `t` in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you can rotate your string t times and it will be the same string. Then if you rotate it another len(S)-t times you will definitely get the same string. If we assume that `t>len(S)/2` we straightforwardly get that `len(S)-t<len(S)/2`, so minimal rotation is always `<=len(S)/2`